# Sorting very different voltages and use them to charge batteries

Tags: power-engineering, energy-harvesting

I'm working on a project to produce electricity from a source that can produce sometimes negative, sometimes positive voltages, ranging from mV to kV depending on the situation, with very little current all the time.

My problem is to develop the simplest circuit. To:
a: Turn all the voltage to a usable voltage like 12 V DC.
b: Convert all the remaining voltage into usable amperage.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, (a) I have changed "Kv" (which doesn't make sense as a unit) into "kV" i.e. kilovolts. If you meant something else, please [edit] your question to elaborate. (b) Can you add more details about the voltage source(s)? (c) Please add details of what solutions you have already tried / considered, and why they were not suitable for you That way, it avoids site members wasting their time repeating suggestions that you have already tried / considered. Thanks.

Comment: It could be very difficult to make a circuit that works well throughout such an enormous voltage range. It might make more sense to make a circuit that works over a voltage range of, say, 50-100 V, but which shuts down and somehow protects itself when the input voltage is higher than that.

Comment: OK, I've got to ask. What the heck is this device that produces mV to kV?